# Locally stored video not rendering in WebVR

Tags: webvr, aframe

Basing my code off the [Github example](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/boilerplate/360-video/index.html) I have added my own 360 video but I keeping getting a console error in Chrome.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <video id="video" src="vid.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
      </a-assets>

      <a-videosphere src="#video" rotation="0 180 0"></a-videosphere>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

I receive the following error:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Can you post your code and where you are getting the video?

Comment: I have the video stored locally, I stitched it together using a video stitching software, and injected the metadata to be a 360 video

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

1. Make sure the file is being referenced correctly (from the location of the index file).
2. Your environment is installed correctly.
3. Your local server is up and running.